# jquery ui layout customization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-layout

I like to make the ui-layout-west section fixed width and like to hide the resizable bar. I tried this but I still see the right border of ui-layout-pane.

on css:

```
.ui-layout-west { 
    background: #F8F8FF  !important;  
    width: 300px !important;

}
```

and on Java script:

```
west: {                  
    enableCursorHotkey: false,                 
    closable: false,
    resizable: false,
    panespacing: 0 
}
```

Any ideas about how to remove teh resiable bar or hide it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying the [spacing_open](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/documentation.cfm#Option_spacing_open) and [spacing_closed](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/documentation.cfm#Option_spacing_closed) options instead of `panespacing`:

```
west: {
    enableCursorHotkey: false,
    closable: false,
    resizable: false,
    spacing_open: 0,
    spacing_closed: 0
}
```